# Getting no space between image and div

Tags: html, css, space

I just wanted to create a newsbox just by using CSS without so many IMG or TABLE crap. It works quite well but there will always appear a space between my image and the colored bar under the picture which should be directly under the picture not with some space between. Here is my code :

```
<div id="mainbody">
  <div class="news_box">
    <div class="news_box_inside">
      <img src="img/newsbox1.jpg" width="270" height="140" border="0" />
      <div class="news_box_bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#mainbody {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.news_box {
  float:left;
  width:288px;
  height:348px;
  background-color:#DDDDDD;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  border:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#BBBBBB;
}

.news_box_inside {
  float:left;
  margin:9px;
  width:270px;
  height:330px;
  background-color:#FCFCFC;
}

.news_box_bar {
  background-color:#540000;
  height:43px;
  border:1px solid #892d2d;
}
```

I tried to set the margin and padding to zero for the image or trying position: or top: but somehow I can't get rid of the space. Anyone got a good solution ?

Best regards,

Kris

Comment: Is this  http://jsfiddle.net/d2aDF/ what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.news_box_inside > img {
    display: block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/TV4zT/

Answer (score 1):

Kris,

If you inspect `<img>` element by default it's `css` property `display` is set to `inline-block`, SO I suggest to apply style on `<img>` element and make it `display:block`

```
<img src="img/newsbox1.jpg" width="270" height="140" border="0" style="display:block" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgcRL/1/)

Comment: GREAT - that helped me a lot :)
I just added
    .news_box_inside img {
      display:block
    }
and now it works perfectly

Comment: Default css display property for `<img>` is `inline`, not `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin to your newsbar as showm: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d2aDF/)

```
.news_box_bar {
  background-color:#540000;
  height:43px;
  border:1px solid #892d2d;
  margin-top:-5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.news_box_bar {
  background-color:#540000;
  margin-top:-5px;
 height:43px;
  border:1px solid #892d2d;
}
```

set this in your CSS class

Answer (score 0):

use link below to see working solution for your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/v7NwR/

```
<div id="mainbody">
  <div class="news_box">
   <div class="news_box_inside">
    <figure><img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/a04d6b3e25c747f48ef794d13e765425.jpg"  border="0" /></figure>
      <div class="news_box_bar">sdfgsdfgsdfg</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.news_box{ float:left; border:5px #444 solid;}
figure{  font-size:0%;}

#mainbody{ color:#000;}
.news_box_bar{ background:red;}
```